# Custom regex - input validation

Tags: java, regex

I need to validate input in the following way.

```
1,1 // true (1)
-1,1 // true (2)
1,-1 // true (3)
-1,-1 // true (4)
```

I enter a positive or negative integer as an input according to the scheme **number,number**.
So far I was able to write this regex `^-?[1-9]\\d*(\\,\\d+)?$` but it doesn't work for the condition (3) and (4). How to fix this regex to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```java
text.matches("-?[1-9]\\d*,-?[1-9]\\d*")
```

Mind that `matches` requires a full string match, thus `^` and `$` anchors are not necessary.

**Details**

- `-?` - an optional `-` char
- `[1-9]` - a non-zero digit
- `\d*` - any zero or more digits.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7ZfvEl/1).